# sqlite3, how properly use subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, delete-record

I am beginner in the sql querying, could please explain me how can I solve such problem.

Problem, lets say I have 2 tables:

```
Table A: has a_id_1, a_id_2
Table_B: has b_id_1, b_id_2
```

and these tables has such records:

```
Table A: has (1,2)
Table A: has (4,5)
Table A: has (7,10)

Table B: has (1,2)
Table B: has (2,1)
Table B: has (7,1)
Table B: has (4,10)
Table B: has (1,10)
Table B: has (10,1)
```

So, my question is, how can I write query to delete records from Table B based on Table A, and if Table B record: b_id_1 != b_id_2 and b_id_2 != b_id_1 delete such record.

I guess I have to use subqueries, but I am not sure how properly use it in this specific case.

I am using sqlite3.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I can't quite tell if you really have two tables or if you are trying to remove "reversed" duplicates in `b`.

Comment: Here is different example:

Tables: Highschooler(ID int, name text, grade int); Friend(ID1 int, ID2 int); Likes(ID1 int, ID2 int);
Data: Friend: (1689, 1709);
          Friend: (1501, 1934);
          Friend: (1316, 1934);

          Likes: (1689, 1709);
          Likes: (1709, 1689);
          Likes: (1782, 1709);

If two students A and B are friends, and A likes B but not vice-versa, remove the Likes tuple.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`, something like this:

```
delete from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where b.b_id_1 = a.b_id_2 and b.b_id_2 = a.b_id_1);
```

Your column names and examples are a bit confusing, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry if my question sounds confusing English is my second language.I definitely will try to implement you answer.